# How to get addressfield geocoded on import with Feeds?

Tags: 7, feeds, entities

I am using Drupal 7.10 with the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module 7.x-2.0-alpha4. The data I'm importing has address data that will be imported into my content type's [address field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield), and the content type is also using the field implemented in the [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield) module, which holds coordinates and it is set to be populated from the address field when a node is saved.

However, when I import the data into nodes, the nodes are not geocoded; if I then edit the node, and save it, the node will be geocoded, and my map will display.

How can I get the Feeds module to trigger geocoding upon data import?

I just found an issue about this: [Feeds + Addressfield Integration](http://drupal.org/node/1265036).

**UPDATE**

Found the issue about "[Creating Your First Map Using OpenLayers, Geocoder, and Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/node/1365574)" which references a patch. I tried this patch and re-imported my nodes. However they still were not geocoded.

Comment: Downvoted and voted to close.  It would be helpful if people gave some indication as to why.  As it stands now, this is still an outstanding problem which I need a solution to.

Answer (score 1):

The way that your Geocoded data will populate after save indicates that there is some hook in the geocoding module that triggers after a save. Perhaps the initial save in feeds bypasses this.

I suggest you find in the Geocode module the point at which this save is triggered, but as a work around for you which should work, trigger another save once feeds has saved your node.

Create a custom module with a [`hook_feeds_after_save`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21feeds%21feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_after_save/7), then call `$entity->save()` on it again to issue a re-save and that should force your Geocoded values to populate.